# regular expression backslash and doublequote with exception

Tags: regex

I want the regular expression for getting every line with 1 "word" and not 1 "otherExpression".

sample : 
get every line with expression '\"' (once or more), and not expression 'otherExpression'

```
otherExpression1 \"
otherExpression 2 \"
\"
word \"
word
anything \"word\" here
before \"word    
something
```

result

```
\"
word \"
anything \"word\" here
before \"word
```

sample 2

with goodExpression and not badExpression

```
badExpression goodExpression 
goodExpression 
this is goodExpression 
this is badExpression
goodExpression2
badExpression1
```

result

```
goodExpression 
this is goodExpression
goodExpression2
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: its a regular expression, you can test on http://www.rubular.com/r/ycXD9zcRxJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!.*otherExpression).*(\\\")
```

Group 1 has your matched `\"`

You haven't said what language you're using, but I have assumed escaping of double quote is required.

Comment: need to change to ^(?!.*otherExpression).*(\\\")

Comment: @forX are you sure about the escaping? regex:`\\"` is needed just to match literal:`\"`,, regex:`\\\"` will match literal:`\"` only because the 3rd backslash is ignored

Comment: @deathApril it depends what language is being used (not specified by OP). Java for example would require 5 backslashes in the string literal.

Comment: @Bohemian yes and no. regex itself requires 2 backslashes => python:`r'\\"'`, javascript+perl+ruby+...:`/\\"/`, java:`"\\\\\""`,, not sure about VB and C families.. but the question is about regex, not any particular language, so i don't see the justification for 3 backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want. Try this;

```
/^[^(?:otherExpression)].*$/gm
```

Matches;

```
\"
word \"
word
anything \"word\" here
before \"word
```

or this;

```
/^[^(?:otherExpression)].*\"$/gm
```

Matches;

```
\"
word \"
```

or this;

```
/^[^(?:otherExpression)].*\\"$/gm
```

Matches;

```
word \"
```

Finally to really match a word, try this;

```
^[^(?:otherExpression)]\w+\s+\\"$
```

Matches;

```
word \"
```